# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method hasPermissions on channel flutter_audio_recorder)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I use this plugin https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_audio_recorder. I have received the following error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfTIl.png)
 i also write this code to ask the permission

```
 await FlutterAudioRecorder.hasPermissions
```

and also add the permissions in Androidmenifiest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

this code also does not ask the user to enable the permission for audio. 
 please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, it seems like you added the plugin while the app is running can you try rebuilding the app.

Comment: Yes, I rebuild the app many times. but it still not asking audio permission from user.

Comment: Try running this example app after cloning https://github.com/shadow-app/flutter_audio_recorder, https://github.com/shadow-app/flutter_audio_recorder/tree/master/example and see what they're doing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to quit Flutter and run again. Also, make sure that you use the command `flutter pub get` before running your app. If you still get the same error, try `flutter clean` and run your app.

Comment: yes, i quit the setup and run again after adding the permissions. this works now  :)